# perl package variables set through command line

Tags: perl

I have to use a command line argument in Perl to initialize a global variable, which in turn is to be passed to a set of packages to set values of variables in those packages. How do I do that, if suppose my main program is main.pl having argument $opt_n and packages are a.pm, b.pm and c.pm.

Please help.

Comment: What have you considered/tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to accomplish your goal. The first step is getting your command line argument into a variable within main.pl. The command line arguments are available via the pre-defined perl list variable @ARGV. Assuming that there is exactly one command line argument, the following would work:

```
my $opt_n = $ARGV[0];
```

It is a good idea to check whether the correct number of command line arguments have been supplied. For example,

```
if  (not @ARGV) {die "No command line arguments were supplied.\n";}
if  (scalar(@ARGV) > 1) {die "Too many command line arguments were supplied.\n";}
my $opt_n = $ARGV[0];
```

If you expect multiple command line arguments, it is convenient to use the shift operator.

```
my $opt_n = shift @ARGV;
my $opt_o = shift @ARGV;
if  (not defined $opt_o) {die "Too few command line arguments.\n";}
```

To use the value of $opt_n in other packages, you have two choices: 1) make $opt_n global ('our $opt_n' instead of 'my $opt_n'), or 2) pass $opt_n to subroutines from the other packages that store $opt_n in variables accessible to the other packages. The global variable route is simpler, but it produces more interdependent and complex code. If you want to do this, just refer to '$::opt_n' in the other packages.

Using the second method, you would call an A.pm subroutine from main.pl.

```
A::set_opt_n($opt_n);
```

And in A.pm, you would write something like this:

```
package A;

use strict;

my $opt_n;

sub set_opt_n($)
{
    my ($opt_n_from_main) = @_;

    $opt_n = $opt_n_from_main;
    return;
}
```

After set_opt_n is called from main.pl, $opt_n can be used in A.pm. Of course, $opt_n in main.pl and $opt_n in A.pm are two different variables. If the value of one changes, the other will not change automatically. This is very different from using a single global variable $::opt_n (or $main::opt_n).

Comment: Is it not possible to write an expression in each package like $package_var=$global_var and set the global_var only so that package function does not need to be called.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to write 'my $opt_n = $::opt_n;' within A.pm, but you have to be sure that this code executes AFTER $::opt_n is set within main.pl. Maybe you don't need 'my $opt_n' in A.pm at all and can just refer to $::opt_n within this package?

Answer (score 3):

Simplest solution: in each package, create a setter method:

```
package a;

our $global_for_a;

sub set_global_a { $global_for_a = shift; }

1;

#### Your main.pl

# Process GetOpt

a::set_global_a($opt_n);
```

There are fancier things (e.g. automatically call setters based on list of loaded packages) but that's for advanced users who know the innards of Perl.

---

Another alternative is to access main's value directly:

```
# Old code in a.pm
do_stuff($global_for_a);

# Instead, use Main's global:
do_stuff($main::opt_n);
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer to explain "automatically call setters based on list of loaded packages".

Comment: @bvnbhati - I added a second solution to access main's variable. If you want to know how to automatically call setters for all loaded moduels please ask as separate question it has nothing to do with this